# php gmdate show different time in different server

Tags: php

I need a time which is same in different timezone. For this, I have used gmdate('Y-m-d', 'H:i:s'). But it is giving different time in local server and remote server. My code is following :

```
$date = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
var_dump($date);
```

In **localhost** I get :
**2016-06-13 21:26:11**

But in **remove server** I get :
**2016-06-13 08:26:10**

Shouldn't these two be same ? What can I do to make them return same time value ?

Regards,
Tanvir

Comment: Do you have `date.timezone` configured in your php.ini? It seems like your local machine thinks its timezone is UTC.

Comment: In the php.ini I have got the following :                                                           date.timezone = Europe/Paris                                                                                       But shouldn't the gmdate() ignore timezone and give a universal time ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the correct timezone in your local `php.ini`.

`gmdate()` returns the UTC time, but it has to know what the system timezone is. If your system hour is 23:26 and you set `date.timezone` to Europe/Paris (UTC+2 during summer time), it will calculate UTC time as 21:26.

Comment: Is there any way I get same time every where ?